# Toyota vitz 2007 1.3 2szfe gear box replacement

Tags: toyota

hi all I had recently changed the gear box due to massive slipping and late response while moving for N to D with jerk. At that time the gear was not accepting calibration. 
Now the gear box is replaced and calibrated successfully and gear oil is also replace after 50 km done. So, the problem still I'm facing is that the small jerk is not going even after replacing the valve body of gear box. any solution  please......

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect your engine mounts, when they wear out, the torque being applied from shifting into gear can transfer to the entire car, and then you feel a jerking motion.

Also, make sure you used the correct transmission oil, check the viscosity and make sure its not over or under filled.